# Como fazer um cURL que atualize a cada segundo sem precisa atualizar a minha pagina

Tags: php, if, libcurl

Bom eu tenho um codigo em php, com um if e eu gostaria q o if conseguisse pegar a resposta do cURL, só q essa resposta ela atualiza a cada segundo entao fica quase impossivel o if pegar a resposta assim, existe algum jeito de eu fazer com q esse if pegue essa resposta sem precisar eu atualizar a pagina?

```
    <?php

 $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.horario-brasilia.com/");
       $Horas = curl_exec($ch);

if (strpos($Horas, "10:00:00")) {
echo '10 horas';
}

?>
```

Comment: A melhor maneira de fazer isso seria com javascript

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O PHP é interpretado antes do carregamento da página, para você realizar ações após o carregamento você precisa de uma linguagem de script no frontend, que faça essa verificação a cada segundo.

Em Javascript você consegue fazer usando o setInterval que executa uma função a cada x milissegundos.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp